# Bower Error: bower angular resolution unsuitable resolution

Tags: angularjs, bower

I got a fail response that bower angular resolution Unsuitable resolution declared for angular: 1.4.8 bower ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

And my bower.json is

```
{
  "name": "someet-backend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.14.2",
    "angular-material": "0.11.1",
    "angular-route": "1.4.7",
    "angular-local-storage": "0.2.2",
    "ng-lodash": "0.2.3",
    "ng-file-upload": "6.0.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "latest",
    "angular-messages": "1.4.7",
    "ng-tags-input": "~3.0.0",
    "angular-jquery": "~0.2.1",
    "textAngular": "v1.3.0-pre15",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "~1.4.8",
    "moment": "~2.10.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.8"
  }
}
```

I have try to degrade angular as

```
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "1.4.7"
}
,
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "1.4.6"
} 
,
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "1.3.0"
}
```

then return similar response result

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade angular-route, angular-messages to match angular version 1.4.8

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade `Dev_dependencies` as well as resolutions

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.7.8",
    "angular-route": "~1.7.8"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.7.8"
  }
```